# Formalizing Open-Host service

Tags: domain-driven-design

Martin Fowler gives a great example of describing the bounded context concept by the polyseme 'Meter' in the electric utility domain (https://martinfowler.com/bliki/BoundedContext.html) . Depending on the context, 'Meter' at least 3 meanings, which may result in 3 bounded contexts (BCs):

1. connection between the grid and a location -> lets call the corresponding BC 'geo';
2. connection between the grid and a customer -> lets call that BC 'customersupport';
3. the physical meter itself -> lets call that BC 'assetmanagement';

Lets say we want to design Open-Host services for exposing meter information for each bounded contexts: so a public API for meter in geo BC, a second one in customersupport BC and a third one in the assetmanagment BC.

In the electric utility domain we have a Common Information Model - CIM - (https://www.entsoe.eu/digital/common-information-model/) - which is the electric utility industry standard for data exchange, describing both syntax and semantics. For instance it has for entity 'Meter' a 'canonical' model, describing Meter with a global set of attributes that is bounded context independend so to say.

Should the public APIs we intend to design make use of the CIM model as the source model for the published language by selecting the right attributes from the canonical 'Meter' model? We can take the CIM 'Meter' model, select a subset of the relevant attributes according to the bounded contexts and publish the API in json or xml, based on the CIM model and decoupled from the BC application model.

Would this be a way to design Open-Host services for the Meter polyseme Martin Fowler is referring to?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can have a grand unified model which encompasses a number of bounded contexts.  Those contexts can effectively ignore the aspects of the unified model which don't really concern them (and even add their own attributes if it makes sense for their purposes).

It might get tricky if there's some aspect of the unified model which multiple bounded contexts are going to want to process updates for, but that can be worked around in various ways.

Answer (score 0):

> Would this be a way to design Open-Host services for the Meter polyseme Martin Fowler is referring to?

Open Host Service is a pattern involved in bounded context *cooperation*. The idea is to provide a stable API for your service, hiding implementation changes from clients to protect them. For instance, you could split your persistence into 2 databases and still expose a single unified interface. Using the CIM model for your service is a good way to ensure a stable API to your clients, using an open standard. However this has nothing to do with polysemes.

Polyseme is a concept where the same object can have different properties and meaning depending on the bounded context considered. For instance, in an ecommerce application, a product can have:

- a color and size in the customization BC
- a unit price and discount in sales BC
- a count and size in storage BC

*Size* in customization and storage BC could have different meanings. Polysemes do not imply cooperation between these contexts, but is rather about *splitting* your model into distinct bounded contexts, so different business areas stop interfering with each other. This has to do with application architecture regarding RDBMS as write performance bottlenecks in monolithic applications. Why have your database read-lock your product price and discount information when the storage team update the count from their latest inventory ?

Quoting Martin Fowler:

> In those younger days we were advised to build a unified model of the entire business, but DDD recognizes that we've learned that "total unification of the domain model for a large system will not be feasible or cost-effective". So instead DDD divides up a large system into Bounded Contexts, each of which can have a unified model - essentially a way of structuring MultipleCanonicalModels.

Here, he is explicitly referring to stuff like the CIM model when is writes about *a unified model of the entire business*. Basically, what is saying is that you should not use the whole CIM model for your contexts.

> Should the public APIs we intend to design make use of the CIM model as the source model for the published language by selecting the right attributes from the canonical 'Meter' model? We can take the CIM 'Meter' model, select a subset of the relevant attributes according to the bounded contexts and publish the API in json or xml, based on the CIM model and decoupled from the BC application model.

The CIM model is designed for data exchange in this domain. It sounds like a good starting point for your Ubiquitous Language. However, if you don't need your overall system to comply with the CIM model standard, you should definitely split that into smaller bounded contexts.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! It can be the case however that the Ubiquitoue Language of the BC is different than the Published Language of the OHS of that same BC. The OHS service has a different audience than the BC has. So in our example, the OHS can be formalized according to CIM (with an own 'integration model' and language), whereas the BC has its own 'backend' model with own ubiquitous language. With a published language a third party can be involved, this does not hold for the BC. Is this a correct observation?

Comment: If you have different semantics in the OHS and the BC, then languages are not really ubiquitous. It does not mean the model must be identical though.

Comment: True, semantics must be identical, but model and syntactical language can be different.